# Create new variable based on partial matching in column R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, bigdata

I am trying to create a new variable in a data.frame based on something like the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 332L, 332L, 332L, 100L, 100L, 
113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 551L, 551L), icpc = c("D95", "F85", "A01", 
"A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "T08", "P28", "D95", "A04", "B12", 
"D95"), icpc2 = c("F15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A01", 
"", "A01", ""), reg.date = c("19JUN2015", "15AUG2016", "16MAR2010", 
"20JAN2018", "20FEB2017", "01JUN2017", "11JAN2008", "18MAR2018", 
"19JAN2017", "16JAN2013", "01MAY2009", "03APR2011", "09MAY2015"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I've managed with the following code for the new column `condit`:

```
library(data.table)

cond1 <- c("D95", "A01")
setDT(df)[, condit := ifelse(any(icpc %in% cond1 | icpc2 %in% cond1), "yes","no"), by=id]
df
```

However, I am working with a big dataset **(>40 milion)** and also want to categorize based on the letter in `icpc` and `icpc2`.

**My goal is to add a new column which gives `yes` or `no` to there being a letter `A` (so, `A01`, `A04`, `A50` etc.) in either column `icpc` or `icpc2`. I also want all columns with the same `id` to have `yes` in the new column `condit2`.**

I was trying the following:

```
df2 <- setDT(df)[, condit2 := ifelse
                            (any(icpc %in% pmatch("K", df) | icpc2 %in% pmatch("K", df)), "yes","no"), by = PATNR]
head(df2)
```

This kept on running forever... (I guess, df is too bread anyway, if should have been `df$icpc` and `df$icpc2`?)

Than the following to check if `pmatch` is suitable:

```
condit2 <- pmatch("K")
```

And then looked at something totally different:

```
library(sqldf)
condit2 <- sqldf("df$icpc | df$icpc2, '%K%'")
```

**This should result in the following data frame:**

```
    id  icpc icpc2 reg.date    condit2
 1: 123  D95   F15 19JUN2015    no
 2: 123  F85       15AUG2016    no
 3: 332  A01       16MAR2010    yes
 4: 332  A04       20JAN2018    yes
 5: 332  K20       20FEB2017    yes
 6: 100  B10       01JUN2017    yes
 7: 100  A04       11JAN2008    yes
 8: 113  T08       18MAR2018    yes
 9: 113  P28       19JAN2017    yes
10: 113  D95   A01 16JAN2013    yes
11: 113  A04       01MAY2009    yes
12: 551  B12   A01 03APR2011    yes
13: 551  D95       09MAY2015    yes
```

Can anyone give a hint? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setDT(df)

to_check <- 'A'

df[, condit2 := fifelse(any(grepl(to_check, icpc) | grepl(to_check, icpc2)),
                        'yes', 'no'), 
   by = id]

df
#      id icpc icpc2  reg.date condit2
#  1: 123  D95   F15 19JUN2015      no
#  2: 123  F85       15AUG2016      no
#  3: 332  A01       16MAR2010     yes
#  4: 332  A04       20JAN2018     yes
#  5: 332  K20       20FEB2017     yes
#  6: 100  B10       01JUN2017     yes
#  7: 100  A04       11JAN2008     yes
#  8: 113  T08       18MAR2018     yes
#  9: 113  P28       19JAN2017     yes
# 10: 113  D95   A01 16JAN2013     yes
# 11: 113  A04       01MAY2009     yes
# 12: 551  B12   A01 03APR2011     yes
# 13: 551  D95       09MAY2015     yes
```

If, instead of just two columns `icpc` and `icpc2`, you have a bunch of them and don't want to type out the `grepl` code for every one, here's version with `.SDcols` which gives the same result.

```
df[, condit2 := fifelse(any(Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, grepl, patt = to_check))),
                        'yes', 'no'), 
   by = id, .SDcols = patterns('icpc')]
```

Comment: This directed at columns, not values in columns, right?

Comment: It is checking the column values to see if they contain ‘A’

Comment: Wonderful, I see it now. Giving extra options for selecting columns as well. So good. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, fifelse should be ifelse

Comment: fifelse is a data.table function that is like ifelse but faster (hence the f in front)

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` this can be done with the following method:
`group_by(id)`, `paste` the two columns of interest together, and check whether at least one `A` occurred in the concatenated string using `sum` and `grepl`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(condit2 = case_when(sum(grep("A", paste(icpc, icpc2))) > 0 ~ "yes",
                             TRUE ~ "no")) %>% 
  ungroup()


      id icpc  icpc2 reg.date  condit2
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
 1   123 D95   "F15" 19JUN2015 no     
 2   123 F85   ""    15AUG2016 no     
 3   332 A01   ""    16MAR2010 yes    
 4   332 A04   ""    20JAN2018 yes    
 5   332 K20   ""    20FEB2017 yes    
 6   100 B10   ""    01JUN2017 yes    
 7   100 A04   ""    11JAN2008 yes    
 8   113 T08   ""    18MAR2018 yes    
 9   113 P28   ""    19JAN2017 yes    
10   113 D95   "A01" 16JAN2013 yes    
11   113 A04   ""    01MAY2009 yes    
12   551 B12   "A01" 03APR2011 yes    
13   551 D95   ""    09MAY2015 yes
```